# My javascript file is not executing which includes form refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, ajax

Hello I have implemented a contact form and when I submit the form it does trigger but the form in the console (but doesn't send to my inbox yet - that is another story) does not refresh. I have a create.js.erb file which is meant to tell the user if their message was sent or not and refresh the message box but it doesn't work.

[project](https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/CB)

Tried to create a variable and set it to an empty string.

create.js.erb file:

```
console.log("This is the create.js.erb file");

$('#contact').html("<%= j render 'contact_form' %>");
$('#flash-message').html("<%= j render 'flash' %>").delay(3000).fadeOut(4000);

var inputBox = document.getElementById('contact-form-text-area');
inputBox.value = "";
```

messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @contact = Message.new(params[:message])
  end

  def create
    @contact = Message.new(params[:message])
    @contact.request = request

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.deliver!
        # re-initialize Message object for cleared form
        @contact = Message.new
        format.html { render 'index'}
        format.js   { flash.now[:success] = @message = "Thank you for your message. I'll get back to you soon!" }
      else
        format.html { render 'index' }
        format.js   { flash.now[:error] = @message = "Message did not send." }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Message box to refresh when submitted